# Защита от флуда чата

Tags: алгоритм, безопасность

Какие есть варианты защиты анонимного чата от флуда без модерирования канала ? Пока в голове только каптча на ввод текста.

Comment: регистрация, хитрые алгоритмы для стоп-слов, банальный подсчет кол-ва слов в единицу времени.

Comment: Никаких. Модерирование в том или ином виде необходимо.